# How to download gene expression data from NCBI gene database

Tags: rna-seq, database, gene, data-download

In the NCBI gene database, I can add the expression tracks (circled in picture blow) through 'Tracks' button, but **How I can download the expression data directly, not just look the picture?**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can download raw data from SRA (NCBI). On this [website](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genome/annotation_euk/Capra_hircus/102/) under RNA-Seq alignments, you'll find the samples. Click on them, for example [SAMN05231885](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/biosample/?term=SAMN05231885), and then click on [PRJNA325427](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/bioproject/325427) to see the link to the SRA data (click on [1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra?linkname=bioproject_sra_all&from_uid=325427)). Here you can download the raw fastq files of the experiment.